What's the reason for mixing 3D and hand made animation for characters in animes?
I'm watching a series Hazurewaku no "Joutai Ijou Skill" de Saikyou ni Natta Ore ga Subete wo Juurin suru made and they mix 3D and hand made animation for characters all the time. In one scene, they draw the character hand made. The next scene is made in 3D. The following is drawn hand made again. The next is again 3D.
I can understand animes which mix 3D for scenarios and hand made animation for characters but this doesnt make any sense.
What's the reason for doing this? Reducing production costs or something?
